# How to integrate Androidx Paging-3 in Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, clean-architecture, modules, repository-pattern, android-development

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3595916-clean-architecture-tutorial-for-android-getting-started) blog on "Clean Architecture" describes how to build a modular Android application along with using Clean Architecture.

In that example project, the author places the business logic in a separate 'core' module and that module is framework independent. It contains repository classes, use-case classes, and data-source interfaces. All the other framework dependent components go in the 'app' module.

Android Paging library treats its `PagingSource` class as a repo level component. Even `RoomDao` classes have ability to directly return an instance of `PagingSource`. In this case, we used to return `Flow<PagingData>` from the repo methods. But now, we can't have `PagingData` in repo class.

So, how to integrate AndroidX "Paging-3" in an app built inline with "Clean Architecture"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Androidx-paging is a usefull tool that is not compatible with the blog-article proposed architecture:

- Article: usecases are (or should be) platform independent.
- Androidx-paging is platform dependent.

---

Paging is used by the presentation layer when (parts of) lists are displayed.

Affected layers:

- View Layer: (i.e. a RecyclingView to show the page)
- Usecase Layer: (i.e. show page 1 of 15) android-specific Androidx-paging
- Domain-Layer does not use entities but pagingdata
- Repository-Interface: (i.e. get item 1 - 15 of 220 items)

Comment: Ohh.. But the architecture mentioned blog post really looks very neat. I think 'Kotlin multiplatform mobile' also uses similar architecture. So `androidx-paging3` in incompatible with that too :(